# Passing php variables with Paypal buttons

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a problem passing a variable to the Paypal button so that the IPN sent by Paypal can send the data in the variable back to me.

However, when I tested the button, I get the error 'Data does not match input character set or default encoding. For more information, please contact the merchant.'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to the encoding that you have set in your PayPal account for IPN and other things . You can try to change the encoding as "UTF-8" from your PayPal account . Visit the below url to change the encoding settings in your PayPal account .

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding

Once you visit the above url , click on the link which says "MOre Options "